# Including libraries with pub

Tags: dart, dart-pub

How can I include front-end libraries (for example bootstrap) in dart with `pubspec.yaml`? I resolved all dependencies, but browser shows error

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:63342/BattleCity/build/web/html/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

My `pubspec.yaml` looks like this:

```
name: BC
description: An absolute bare-bones web app.
version: 0.0.1
#homepage: https://www.example.com
#author: localroot <email@example.com>

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.20.1 <2.0.0'

#dependencies:
#  path: ^1.4.1

dependencies:
  path: ^1.4.1
  font_awesome: "^4.7.0"
  bootstrap: "^4.0.0"



dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1

transformers:
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter

# Uncomment the following in sdk 1.24+ to make pub serve
# use dartdevc (webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartdevc).
#web:
#  compiler:
#    debug: dartdevc
```

in `index.html` im including bootstrap with following tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

.packages looks as following:

```
# Generated by pub on 2018-06-25 21:00:42.860811.
args:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/args-1.4.3/lib/
async:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-1.13.3/lib/
barback:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/barback-0.15.2+15/lib/
bootstrap:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bootstrap-4.0.0/lib/
browser:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.10.0+3/lib/
charcode:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/charcode-1.1.1/lib/
collection:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/collection-1.14.6/lib/
csslib:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/csslib-0.14.3/lib/
dart_to_js_script_rewriter:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_to_js_script_rewriter-1.0.3/lib/
font_awesome:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/font_awesome-4.7.0/lib/
html:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/html-0.13.3/lib/
logging:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/logging-0.11.3+1/lib/
path:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path-1.5.1/lib/
pool:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pool-1.3.4/lib/
source_span:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/source_span-1.4.0/lib/
stack_trace:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stack_trace-1.9.2/lib/
utf:file:///C:/Users/localroot/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/utf-0.9.0+3/lib/
BC:lib/
```

Comment: The mime-type error indicates that `pub run build_runner` failed to build your code.

Comment: When I build it there is no errors, From bootstrap I need only its css classes. I don't want store it local on my pc and need it as dependency

Comment: A dependency **is** stored locally on your PC.

Comment: I meant, that I don't want donwload it from bootstrap site as file, but use it as pub dependency

Comment: If you remove the bootstrap link does the page show properly?

Comment: You don't need `dart_to_js_script_rewriter` in Dart 2 anymore. Ensure your `<script>` tag points to the JS file instead of a Dart file in `index.html`. Also the `browser` dependency is redundant.

Comment: No. I used earlier I used bootstrap as downloaded files from bootstrap site. For example: web->css->bootstrap.css. Now I removed this file and added as dependency into pubspec,yaml. Then I resolved packages and it doesnt work more, But bootstrap files from dependencies are there(directory build/web/packages/css/bootstrap.css)

Comment: `<script defer src="../src/main1.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
        <script defer src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>`

Comment: -> If you remove the bootstrap link does the page show properly? 

Yes. Only bootstrap classes not working

Comment: looks like you are using an older workflow (`pub serve` maybe?, some other file server directly from the build output?). The issue looks like an incorrect MIME type so the details will depend on how exactly you're serving the files. I think this should work with `pub run build_runner serve`. https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md